# how to get click event of row which is generated on panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please tell me how to get click event of row which is generated on panel .Actually I am able to get event of row which is generated on page.But i used this http://dbushell.com/2012/06/17/nestable-jquery-plugin/
I want to get click event of row which is generated in panel.

I make a simple demo to show nested list in panel. To open the panel there is button on header "open panel".

when you click "add test case button".it generate rows in panel as well in screen.When you click any of row it open new screen .there is another "add test case " button .it generate the nested list in panel

http://jsfiddle.net/VRPMj/1/

I get the click event of row which is on page like that .

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickTestCaseRow', function (e) {
    var clickId = this.id;
    hideDisplayView();
    displayNewView(clickId);
    alert('click')
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

When I do same like that on panel list it not work .:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there seem to be two problems with this

Firstly, the items in the side panel don't have the class `clickTestCaseRow` so the `$(document).on('click'..` doesn't trigger on them.

```
var menuid = "menu_" + id;
    $('#testSuit').append('<li class="dd-item submenu_h" id="' + menuid + '" ><div class="clickTestCaseRow dd-handle" id="' + menuid + '">' + id + '</div></li>')
```

Secondly, it seems the nested list plugin stops mousedown events on its items.
So I've disabled the nested list to check and it works now. Without the drag function of nestable though:

http://jsfiddle.net/VRPMj/3/

To really fix the issue you'd have to fiddle with the nestable plugin itself.
I've had a quick look at it and the issue seems to be on line 104. 
This prevents the mousedown event on the items. So there's a starting point.

```
    var onStartEvent = function(e)
        {
            var handle = $(e.target);
            if (!handle.hasClass(list.options.handleClass)) {
                if (handle.closest('.' + list.options.noDragClass).length) {
                    return;
                }
                handle = handle.closest('.' + list.options.handleClass);
            }
            if (!handle.length || list.dragEl || (!hasTouch && e.button !== 0) || (hasTouch && e.touches.length !== 1)) {
                return;
            }
            e.preventDefault(); // <=== Here
            list.dragStart(hasTouch ? e.touches[0] : e);
        };
```

Comment: but it stop drag drop functionality..is it possible to we can both click and drag and drop functionlity

Comment: Second it is not showing collapsible row http://jsfiddle.net/VRPMj/4/ in nested list .In other word it is not showing + and - when I add dynamically

Comment: @user944513 Right, in my example i disabled the nestable to check if that's causing the problem. I'm not familiar enough with this plugin to know if maybe there's built-in functionality to allow click events. Or if you have to modify nestable yourself or resort to another plugin which does the same. You could take a look at the excellent http://www.jstree.com/ which i think has everything you'd need.

Comment: thanks for help ..can you make one simple static sample on fiddle .in which use static nested list and which have functionality of drag and drop .I will very thankful to you

Comment: if fiddle not permit this .please use simple html send to my mail.naveen.nsit89@gmail.com

Comment: @user944513 Have a look at the documentation and demos http://www.jstree.com/demo/. In the configuration you just have to add "dnd" in the `plugins` array. If you are stuck feel free to post another question so more people can see it and try to help. Good luck!

Comment: i just need static list like using ul and li

Comment: first if i make static than i go to dynamic.. i don't have any array

Comment: i see from morning but i am not able to make example of fiddle that why i am asking ..here is my second same question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23444379/looking-for-js-tree-example-using-jquerry

Comment: @user944513 What do you have problems with exactly? You'll get more answers if you ask about a specific question if you have a problem. Anyways, here's an example with jstree: http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/

Comment: thak i need this only